# React: replace links in a text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the proper way to replace urls in a string and render them as links with React?

Say I have a string: `'hello http://google.com world'`, and I want it to render like: `hello <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> world`

Comment: The same way you would do it in JavaScript?

Comment: This just saved me, and all you goobers who upvoted @HenrikAndersson's comment have apparently never used React.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, so this is how I done it.

```
class A extends React.Component {
  renderText() {
    let parts = this.props.text.split(re) // re is a matching regular expression
    for (let i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
      parts[i] = <a key={'link' + i} href={parts[i]}>{parts[i]}</a>
    }
    return parts
  }
  render() {
    let text = this.renderText()
    return (
      <div className="some_text_class">{text}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I ran into issues with every answer here, so I had to write my own:

```
// use whatever you want here
const URL_REGEX = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/;

const renderText = txt =>
  txt
    .split(" ")
    .map(part =>
      URL_REGEX.test(part) ? <a href={part}>{part} </a> : part + " "
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

There are NPM modules to handle this. Both of these depend on [linkify-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkify-it) ([repo](https://github.com/markdown-it/linkify-it))

## [react-linkify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkify) ([repo](https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify))

```
<Linkify>
  <div>react-linkify <span>(tasti.github.io/react-linkify/)</span></div>
    <div>React component to parse links (urls, emails, etc.) in text into clickable links</div>
  See examples at tasti.github.io/react-linkify/.
    <footer>Contact: tasti@zakarie.com</footer>
</Linkify>
```

At time of writing, the current version is 1.0.0-alpha. It requires React 16. The [repo](https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify) has 14 open tickets and 17 open PRs. So that's not fantastic.

Version 0.2.2 allows much earlier versions but doesn't have link text decoration, etc.

## [react-native-hyperlink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hyperlink) ( [repo](https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-hyperlink) )

If you are using native (ie a phone app), it looks like the better of the two options. Code samples:

```
<Hyperlink linkDefault={ true }>
  <Text style={ { fontSize: 15 } }>
    This text will be parsed to check for clickable strings like https://github.com/obipawan/hyperlink and made clickable.
  </Text>
</Hyperlink>

<Hyperlink onLongPress={ (url, text) => alert(url + ", " + text) }>
  <Text style={ { fontSize: 15 } }>
    This text will be parsed to check for clickable strings like https://github.com/obipawan/hyperlink and made clickable for long click.
  </Text>
</Hyperlink>

<Hyperlink
  linkDefault
  injectViewProps={ url => ({
        testID: url === 'http://link.com' ? 'id1' : 'id2' ,
        style: url === 'https://link.com' ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'blue' },
        //any other props you wish to pass to the component
  }) }
>
  <Text>You can pass props to clickable components matched by url.
    <Text>This url looks red https://link.com
  </Text> and this url looks blue https://link2.com </Text>
</Hyperlink>
```

### References

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3148
- [REACT - How to replace URL strings to <a> elements and rendering it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158984/react-how-to-replace-url-strings-to-a-elements-and-rendering-it-properly)

Answer (score 7):

Try this library, it does exactly you need:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-process-string

An example from there:

```
const processString = require('react-process-string');

let config = [{
    regex: /(http|https):\/\/(\S+)\.([a-z]{2,}?)(.*?)( |\,|$|\.)/gim,
    fn: (key, result) => <span key={key}>
                             <a target="_blank" href={`${result[1]}://${result[2]}.${result[3]}${result[4]}`}>{result[2]}.{result[3]}{result[4]}</a>{result[5]}
                         </span>
}, {
    regex: /(\S+)\.([a-z]{2,}?)(.*?)( |\,|$|\.)/gim,
    fn: (key, result) => <span key={key}>
                             <a target="_blank" href={`http://${result[1]}.${result[2]}${result[3]}`}>{result[1]}.{result[2]}{result[3]}</a>{result[4]}
                         </span>
}];

let stringWithLinks = "Watch this on youtube.com";
let processed = processString(config)(stringWithLinks);

return (
    <div>Hello world! {processed}</div>
);
```

That will replace all links with or without "http://" protocol. If you want to replace only links with protocol, remove the second object from config array.

Answer (score 4):

First add `<a>` tag to string:

```
function httpHtml(content) {
  const reg = /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)((\w|=|\?|\.|\/|&|-)+)/g;
  return content.replace(reg, "<a href='$1$2'>$1$2</a>");
}

console.log(httpHtml('hello http://google.com world'))
// => hello <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> world
```

Then render string as html in react:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: httpHtml('hello http://google.com world')
  }} />;
}
```

Comment: But this would mean that the text also interprets html, so the text "<script>alert('hello')</script>" also would compile and run?

Comment: @einord Yes, the function doesn't filter `script` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a short function to do it:

```
const RE_URL = /\w+:\/\/\S+/g;

function linkify(str) {
  let match;
  const results = [];
  let lastIndex = 0;
  while (match = RE_URL.exec(str)) {
    const link = match[0];
    if (lastIndex !== match.index) {
      const text = str.substring(lastIndex, match.index);
      results.push(
        <span key={results.length}>{text}</span>,
      );
    }
    results.push(
      <a key={results.length} href={link} target="_blank">{link}</a>
    );
    lastIndex = match.index + link.length;
  }
  if (results.length === 0) {
    return str;
  }
  if (lastIndex !== str.length) {
    results.push(
      <span key={results.length}>{str.substring(lastIndex)}</span>,
    );
  }
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

late to the party but here's a slightly modified version :

```
export const linkRenderer = (string: string):ReactNode => {
    const linkExp = /^https?:\/\/[a-z0-9_./-]*$/i
    return <>{
        string.split(/(https?:\/\/[a-z0-9_./-]*)/gi).map((part, k) => <React.Fragment key={k}>
            {part.match(linkExp) ? <a
                href={part}
                onFocus={(e) => { e.stopPropagation() }}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noreferrer"
            >{part}</a>
            : part}
        </React.Fragment>)
    }</>
}
```

Interesting things to note there:

- it doesn't split on space or blank space so preserving existing spaces
- It create less chunks by only splitting parts where link are not every word or so
- the regexp passed to split must have capturing parenthesis if you want to have your links as part of the resulting array.
- the noreferrer attribute is required with target blank for security reason on older browsers

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's own answer I came up with the one-liner:

```
{text
  .split(/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi)
  .map((part, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? part : <a href={part} target="_blank">{part}</a>
}
```

Comment: This transforms the url into a clickable link but replaces the https protocol and also the url root with your server (i.e.: localhost) so the final url is invalid

Answer (score 0):

for me, i managed to solve it this way

```
const ActiveProblem = () => {
  const { activeProblem } = useProblems();
  const id = new Date().toString();
  const match = activeProblem.replace(
    urlPattern,
    (matched) => id + matched + id
  );

  return (
      <Typography align="center" variant="body1" color="white">
        {match.split(id).map((str, idx) => {
          if (str.match(urlPattern))
            return (
              <Box component="a" href={str} key={id + idx}>
                {str}
              </Box>
            );
          return str;
        })}
      </Typography>
  );
};
```

I'm using Material UI with React

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with [`react-link-parser`](https://amir2mi.github.io/react-link-parser) package.

```bash
yarn add react-link-parser
```

```
import LinkParser from "react-link-parser";

export function App() {
  return (
    <LinkParser>
     I know you will forgive me for it. Were not my other associations so chosen by Fate as to make a heart like mine uneasy? Read more here: https://lorem.ipsum/book
    </LinkParser>
  );
}
```

Ultimately you can define watchers to target emails and mentions and so on.

```
import LinkParser from "react-link-parser";

export function App() {

  return (
    <LinkParser watchers={watchers}>
      #Far_far_away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries @Vokalia and @Consonantia, there live the blind
      texts. Separated they live in @Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics*, a large language ocean. A
      small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. \n Credit: \n
      https://www.blindtextgenerator.com/lorem-ipsum \n Contact Me: happy.cactus@mail.me
    </LinkParser>
  );
}
```

[image: react link parser library]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hope this helps someone

```
function convertTextToLinks(text) {
  const urlRegex = /(^|\s)(https?:\/\/[^\s]+|www\.[^\s]+|[\w-]+\.com[^\s]*)/g;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, (match, space, url) => {
    let originalUrl = url;
    if (url.startsWith("www.")) {
      url = `https://${url}`;
    } else if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
      url = `https://www.${url}`;
    }
    return `${space}<a href="${url}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">${originalUrl}</a>`;
  });
}
```

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const textString = "Your text string with links here";
  const convertedText = convertTextToLinks(textString);

  return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: convertedText }} />
  );
}
```

Always remember to sanitize your dangerouslySetInnerHTML by using a package like DOMPurify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify)

Update with sanitization:

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(convertedText) }}`