# REACT - How to replace URL strings to <a> elements and rendering it properly

Tags: reactjs, replace, anchor

Given the following content:

```
Hi Christine,

Are you receiving?
--
Daniel Vieira Costa.
Frontend Developer | Zeuss, Inc.
Know It's Possible.
http://www.zeuss.com
```

I want to replace all URL (e.g. http://www.zeuss.com) to `<a>` elements/objects and render it within a React content.

My base code is the following:

```
// regular expression used to find out all URL occorrences
let regexpression = /(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/ig;

// replace all URL occurrences to <a> elements
content = content.replace(regexpression, newLink => {
    return <a>{newLink}</a>
})
```

However, the it's rendering the following result:

```
Hi Christine, 

Are you receiving?
--
Daniel Vieira Costa.
Frontend Developer | Zeuss, Inc.
Know It's Possible.
[object Object]
```

Where `[object Object]` should be the `<a>` element.

I would like to avoid raw HTML with React (setting the `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` attribute). Is there a better implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are creating with that syntax is a react element, what oyu want is a string though, so try:

`return '<a>' + newLink + '</a>'`

You will have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` anyway as you will have a string with HMTL inside after your replace operation.

Add on answering to the comment:

You might actually get away with doing this by first splitting the string at the URLs, then put it back together in a JSX expression.

So given you manage to split the string into an array like this (should be doable but I leave that part to you):

```
let splitString = ['Hi Christine,

Are you receiving?
--
Daniel Vieira Costa.
Frontend Developer | Zeuss, Inc.
Know It's Possible.', 'http://www.zeuss.com']

let parsedResult = splitString.map((part) => {
    if (part.matches(regexpression)) {
       return <a>{part}</a>
    }
    return part
})

return <div>{parsedResult}</div>
```

This should work without using dangerouslySetInnerHtml.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'd like to avoid the using of dangerouslySetInnerHtml to avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: See addon in answer.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to test it right now and let you know.